# Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' pero ya esta agregada la cabecera

Tags: cors, backend, slim

Tengo una API en php y la estoy consumiendo desde una app hecha con Vue (las peticiones las hago con axios). el asunto es que las tengo ambas desplegadas en heroku, cuando intento hacer un PUT o un DELETE me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://mystore.test/api/usuarios/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

seguido de:

```
POST http://mystore.test/api/usuarios/login net::ERR_FAILED
```

algo curioso es que cuando hago la peticion desde el `origin: http://localhost:8080` no me permite hacer ni las peticiones GET ni POST.

cuando hago GET y POST no hay problema.
he leido en la documentacion que deberia resolverse agregando:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

o en el `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

ya intente ambas maneras pero me sigue arrojando el mismo error.

PD: no se si tenga que ver pero estoy utilizando el framework Slim para el backend y la documentacion que da tampoco es espesifica sobre este problema

Answer (score 0):

espero que tal vez aun sea tiempo de salvar esto.

Yo tenia el mismo tipo de problema, Solo que mi caso es desde ReactJS Lo unico que hice fue cambiar las cabeceras de PHP con las siguientes:

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Allow: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Mi .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

No entendia el por qué me generaba esa clase de errores, pero como tal es PHP quien genera problemas, y mi solución fue usar esos headers.

Esto es lo unico con lo que puedo intentar ayudar, ya que no ha mostrado mucho de como envia y recibe la información.